Invalid Scopes error when try to choose get page access token in Graph API Explorer
I'm try to access Facebook API  and when I try to choose get page access token in Graph API Explorer because user access token only gives permission to email. But it gives error :
    Error
Invalid Scopes: manage_pages, pages_show_list. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

but in the doc it says

If your app is in development, you can grant your app any permission
and your queries respect them for data owned by people with a role on
your app. If your app is live, however, granting a permission that
your app has not been approved for by the App Review process causes
your query to fail whenever you submit it.

my app in development mode too.

This is the Error:

Anyone know a fix?
